# Assert\Regex and TypeGuessing

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have following entity field:

```
/**    
* @Assert\Regex(
*   pattern = "/^d+\.(jpg|png|gif)$/",
*   htmlPattern = "/^d+\.(jpg|png|gif)$/"
* )
**/

protected $src;
```

The form is created by something like this:

```
$builder
   ->add('src', TextareaType::class, array( //neither is TextType::class working
      'attr' => array('class' => 'mysrc'),
)); //pattern will not be rendered
```

The problem is, as soon as I provide the field type class `TextareaType::class` the regex pattern isn't rendered as constraint to the form. Or in other words: The regex pattern is only rendered, if the field type is guessed:

```
$builder
   ->add('src', null, array(    
      'attr' => array('class' => 'mysrc'),
)); //pattern will be rendered
```

Any workaround? I want to have the regex patterns in one place, i.e. in my entity, not in a controller or a form.

Answer (score 3):

Yepp, this is how it should work. Not only the field type is guessed, but some options too and if the type is not guessed the options neither.

BTW the textarea element does not support the pattern attribute, but if you want to you can add one: `'attr' => array('pattern' => '/jsregex/')`, you should use a different pattern for the client side than the server side anyway. If you want to give the pattern in one place use a [constant](http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations.html#constants).

Comment: In fact, symfony append the `pattern` attribute to the `TextareaType`, but only if the type is guessed, and it's effectively useless because of non-supported attribute. One more validation problem due to the difference between type guessing and manual type definition. Interesting question.

Comment: Thx for the info. I'm ok, if the pattern is only passed, even if it's not supported by textarea. And the problem remains with `TextType`

Comment: You can pass it as an attribute option on the field if you want or use `Column(type="text")` and it will be guessed as a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one could help you:

**FormType**

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;
use YourBundle\Entity\YourEntity;

public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}

public function getRegexPattern($property)
{
    $pattern = null;
    $metadata = $this->validator->getMetadataFor(new YourEntity());
    $propertyMetadata = $metadata->getPropertyMetadata($property);
    $constraints = $propertyMetadata[0]->constraints;

    foreach($constraints as $constraint) {
        if ($constraint instanceof Regex) {
            $pattern = $constraint->pattern;
        }
    }

    return $pattern;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('src', TextType::class, array(
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'mysrc',
            'pattern' => $this->getRegexPattern('src')
        ),
    )); 
}
```

**services.yml** (Needed to inject validator in type)

```
services:
    app.form.type.your_entity_type:
        class: YourBundle\Form\YourEntityType
        arguments:
            validator: "@validator"
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

**Rendered**

```
<input type="text" pattern="/^d+\.(jpg|png|gif)$/" class="src"/>
```

Like this, even if the `TextType` in manually set, you get the html validation through pattern retrieved from the constraints of the property.